# Loading indicator for long (non-AJAX) function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, loading

I have a function in my Vue app which takes some time (about 2-3 seconds) to complete. It is **not** an AJAX call.

I would like to include a loading indicator while this code executes, but I am having trouble accomplishing it. I thought I could do the following...

```
<div v-on:click="doThings()">{{stuff}}</div>

methods: {
    doThings: function () {

        this.loading = true
        console.log(this.loading)

        longFunction()

        this.loading = false
        console.log(this.loading)

    }...
}
```

...but that doesn't work. doThings() seems to not execute anything until longFunction() is done. I even tried making a separate function and changing my button to perform two functions like this...

```
<div v-on:click="doLoading(); doThings();">{{stuff}}</div>
```

...but this is also doesn't work. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Is that the only way to achieve this? Some kind of separate thread?

Comment: I asked this question when I was iterating over a lot of objects using a library "lazy.js".  That synchronous operation took a while.  Any use-case where you're awaiting a synchronous function is best handled via a worker.  Keep in mind it's rare to encounter this use-case in real world web applications, since usually the heavy lifting should be done on the server to prevent a bad user experience.

Comment: Yeah, I'm making a sort of...research demo...and I am relying on client side rendering for a couple reasons. Pity there isn't an easy workaround for this.

Comment: Yeah it definitely shoves the "single threaded" nature of javascript in your face, but I think in the long run it's very helpful for newcomers.  Multi threaded applications get complex real quick.  So I learned to appreciate the web worker construct.  In my experience the workers aren't too cumbersome.  Definitely takes a day or two to learn the basics, but once you get a worker working, making modifications to your domain logic is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async code for longFunction() and set `this.loading` to false after the Promise is resolved.

```
<div v-on:click="doThings()">{{stuff}}</div>

methods: {
    doThings: function () {
        this.loading = true
        longFunction().then(() => {
            this.loading = false
        })
    }
}
```

```
var longFunction = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     window.setTimeout(()=>{ //  force a new (pseudo)thread
         // do stuff, then
         resolve()
     },100); // ...some reasonably short interval. One millisecond is working for me when testing locally,  but it might be better to include some extra buffer, to ensure Vue is in its next tick
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass an object reference to longFunction that your Vue component can `watch` for changes on, and use that as the signal back to the component that it can set `loading` to false.

Comment: This was my thought as well, but the problem with it is that when "do stuff" is on the same thread then Vue never gets the chance to update the DOM.

Comment: Aaaaahh, really? OK back to the drawing board I guess

Comment: This is where I'm playing with it: if you comment out the settimeout, and uncomment the longFunction it just never updates the DOM. I expect because the promise immediately executes, and the long function takes over the thread. Using the setTimeout works, but it has to be a certain amount of time (here 50). I *think* it has to be *longer* than $nextTick but Im not sure what the tick value is in Vue. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VrLQWY?editors=1010

Comment: This was a good answer, but unfortunately yes what Bert said is true :(

Comment: I've been testing this out -- yes, a `window.setTimeout` inside the longFunction does work; or if you can put longFunction inside the component itself `this.$nextTick` is enough...  rewriting the answer, bear with me.

Comment: Could you submit a barebones answer with your code for this, Daniel? EDIT: I see your updated answer now

Comment: Heh; now I'm a little confused, I'm testing this locally and it seems to be working even without the setTimeout; still trying to sort out why I'm getting different results than you guys.

Comment: yup, I was being dumb, it's definitely necessary.  Thank you for that, @Bert! I wouldn't have noticed it because i was using setTimeout to create a fake delay in the first place...